# Websocket-Rails and IE 8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer, websocket

I'm working on a real-time chat application using the [websocket-rails gem](https://github.com/websocket-rails/websocket-rails) and am having difficulty in getting real-time updates to happen in Internet Explorer 8.

There's an option at the bottom of the initializer that enables IE8/9 compatibility with enabling CORS:

```
  # Supporting HTTP streaming on Internet Explorer versions 8 & 9
  # requires CORS to be enabled for GET "/websocket" request.
  # List here the origin domains allowed to perform the request.
  config.allowed_origins = ['http://localhost:3000']
```

I've enabled this for development and it worked VERY sporadically and unpredictably. I was able to have a message appear once or twice but never consistently and have since not been able to recreate it again.

Does anyone have any experience with getting websocket-rails and IE to work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I recently did some work similar to this, and have to write a middleware for usurping calls made by IE8 through IE10 and rewriting them to form proper CORS statements. It might help to create a middleware, throw a debugger in it, and see what's trying to be passed through, and why its failing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [WebSocketJS, a polyfill for WebSocket](https://github.com/gimite/web-socket-js)

I would rather use a polyfill to have a socket connection, that trying to emulate one using HTTP requests.